# How to check if a process is ignoring or handling a signal?

Tags: c, linux, signals

Using `signal()` or, preferably, `sigaction()`, we can choose to ignore or explicitly handle most of the [POSIX signals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_(IPC)#POSIX_signals). For example, in order to ignore `SIGCHLD` we could do the following:

```
struct sigaction sa_chld = { .sa_handler = SIG_IGN };
sigaction(SIGCHLD, &sa_chld, NULL);
```

Is there also a way to figure out if a given signal is being ignored and/or caught by the program?

Ideally, I'd like to distinguish if a signal...

- is being handled as per the [default actions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_(IPC)#Default_action)
- is being ignored explicitly
- is being caught explicitly

Comment: `sigaction()` accepts three parameters. If the second is NULL, nothing happens, but the current action is returned via the third parameter.

Comment: It may be worth noting that, as an alternative to setting signal _disposition_ via `sigaction()`, a process can also deal with signals by [_masking_](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_sigmask.html) and then [_accepting_](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigtimedwait.html) them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

Example:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
void h(int Sig){(void)Sig; }
int main()
{
    signal(1,SIG_IGN); //note: setting ign/dfl is more compat (and still safe) with signal()
    sigaction(2, &(struct sigaction){.sa_handler=h},0);

    for(int i=1; i<8; i++){
        struct sigaction oldsa;
        sigaction(i, 0, &oldsa);
        if(!(oldsa.sa_flags&SA_SIGINFO)){
            if(oldsa.sa_handler==SIG_IGN) printf("%d ignored\n", i);
            else if(oldsa.sa_handler==SIG_DFL) printf("%d defaulted\n", i);
            else goto caught;
        }else caught:
            printf("%d caught\n", i);
    }

}
```

Example output:

```
1 ignored
2 caught
3 defaulted
4 defaulted
5 defaulted
6 defaulted
7 defaulted
```

Nonportably on Linux, you can also parse `/proc/$PID/stat` (or `status`, which has the human-readable version) to see if the signal is in the caught/ignored mask for the process
(`if(mask&(1ul<<(signalnumber-1)) printf("%d in the mask", signalnumber);` ).

Linux maintains the list of caught/ignored signals as bitmasks, but POSIX doesn't expose those and instead requires you to obtain each individual disposition seperately vi a non-setting call to `sigaction`.

Comment: I was reading the man page for `sigaction()` before asking the question, yet I've missed that it can also be used to examine a signal action in addition to setting it. Nice.

Answer (score 4):

For a running process, you can check out `/proc/PID/status` and check the fields `SigBlk`, `SigIgn`, and `SigCgt` for blocked, ignored, and caught signals respectively.

Someone wrote a [utility script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/85365/192153) handy to "decode" it which I personally find very useful and been using it.

See [`proc`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) documentation for details and more relevant fields.

Comment: No `/proc` in MacOS and presumably every other BSD.  Any other ideas?

Comment: @Devon You can use `ps`: `ps -o pid,sigignored,sigblocked -p <pid>`. You can also use `proc_pidinfo` interface.

Comment: `ps: sigignored: keyword not found`
`ps: sigblocked: keyword not found`
# `man -k pidinfo`
`pidinfo: nothing appropriate`